# SQL: Split table on rank

Tags: sql-server, analytics, data-manipulation

I have a table in SQL Server that I want to split into N amount of tables.

The data is imported from a spreadsheet, and the sub-table delimiter is a blank line.

The data appears like this:

```
Vendor    AccountNumber    InvoiceNumber    Amount
ABC       123456           ABC-123456-1     $100
ABC       123456           ABC-123456-1     $75

DEF       123456           DEF-123456-1     $100
DEF       123456           DEF-123456-1     $75

XYZ       123456           XYZ-123456-1     $100
XYZ       123456           XYZ-123456-1     $75
```

I basically want to split this into N amount of tables, based on the combination of Vendor, Account number and invoice number. So with the above example, I would end up with 3 tables.

I can think of 2 ways to do this:

- A ranking function like RANK() (PARTITION BY Vendor, Account, Invoice). Then use a cursor to iterate through each interval in the rank, and create a new table
- Use the blank line somehow to determine where one "sub-table" ends, and another begins

Just looking for some guidance/suggestions

Cheers

Comment: Please provide some details on why you want it to be split into multiple tables?

Comment: Remember that in relational databases there is no inherent order. You need to have some sort of row ID in there before you can start pulling the first n rows into table 1, second n rows into table 2 etc.

Comment: Yeah I was going to add a rowId identity. Also, why does it matter what I'm using it for? I've given an example and told you that I need it done?

Comment: Could be done easily using SSIS, which would probably be the most efficient for huge input files.

Comment: The input won't be very large. Suffice it to say that I can't use SSIS, I can get the data into SQL, in this format.